# Ancient hindu Meditation books

Tags: meditation

Ancient books list?
Thank you in advance. I am in search of meditation books.
A list of them please help

Comment: What do you mean by meditation book?

Comment: @Yoga books like shiv samhita but with more description of techniques.

Comment: @Yoga books like shiv samhita but with more description of techniques.

Comment: Shiva Samhita. Hatha Yoga Pradipika and Gheranda Samhita are the only ancient books on Yoga .. others will be recent (not ancient).. In Tantras you can also find some info regarding meditation, but best to directly learn from the teacher .. all books will have superficial info only @PravinRGMishra